# Can i define custom tag in HTML 4?

Tags: html

Custom tag in HTML (Please note, i am not saying **Xhtml**).

It's a one line question and i have to write blah blah blah for stackoverflow to let me post this question.

Comment: Sure you can, here's how - blah blah blah blah.

Comment: Blue Dog, don't you agree that stackoverflow should allow one line questions?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can - `<custom-tag></custom-tag>`

Please see [here for more information on custom tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301515.aspx).

Comment: Have a source you can reference? Otherwise this is just an opinion.

Comment: The article you linked is specific to IE 5 or later. What does HTML 4 standard say?

Comment: The article release date is May 2000, it would suggest it applies to html4.

Comment: etr, I don't think, we should imply html4 from date. At that time, MS was fooling itself with the dreams of IE dominance in future and thus, was adding propriety features in IE.